# Manipulate a list: replace random position of a specific integer n times by 0

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, random

I have this matrix with 3 sublists:

```
d = {{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
    1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
```

For learning purposes, I try to replace integer 1 (randomly 3 times) in each sublist with 0.

The output can be like this after replace number 1 in a random position of each sublist by 0 tree times:

```
new d = {{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ReplacePart`:

```
d = {{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
    1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};

f = ReplacePart[#, RandomSample[Position[#, 1], 3] -> 0]&

Print[f /@ d]
(* {{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z9FwVahutpQRwGIDMAknG0AZ9TqKFTjkgSLcCkAgSFUmQGqMlSTaq25uNKAdgalFuQkJqcGJBaVRCvrKAQl5qXk5wYn5hbkpEYH5BdnlmTm54EkDGN1FIxjFXTtFAxi1bi4Aooy80qi0xT0HRRSYv//BwA)

If you want it to work on lists that contain fewer than 3 1s, replacing them all with 0s, use `UpTo[3]` instead of `3`.

Comment: That's great.#lirtosiast. One question more, please. How I can use If function. I want to pick randomly 3 elements from each sublist in matrix d and replace by if  0->1, or 1->0

Comment: @BenAawf `MapAt` (used in klgr's answer) is more general than `ReplacePart`; you can do for instance `f = MapAt[1-#&, #, RandomSample[Position[#, 0 | 1], 3]]&`, which does your replacement and leaves all elements not 0 or 1 unchanged.

Answer (score 5):

```
MapAt[0 &, #, RandomSample[Position[#, 1], UpTo@3]] & /@ d
```

> {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>     1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

```
Module[{s= SparseArray[RandomSample[Position[#, 1], UpTo@3] -> 0, Length@#, 1]}, s #] & /@ d
```

> {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>     1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

```
SubsetMap[{0, 0, 0} &, #, RandomSample[Position[#, 1], UpTo@3]] & /@ d
```

> {{1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

Comment: wooow that's so helpful thank you so much @kglr

Answer (score 3):

A function that takes a list and replaces a random 1 by a 0:

```
replaceone[L_] := ReplacePart[L, RandomChoice[Position[L, 1]][[1]] -> 0]
```

Apply it three times to all sublists of `d`:

```
Nest[replaceone, #, 3] & /@ d
(*    {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll throw my hat in the ring.

```
f[list_, numtorep_, numofreps_] := Block[
 {data = list}, 
 Apply[
  (data[[##]] = 0) &, 
  RandomSample[#, numofreps] & /@ GatherBy[Position[list, numtorep], First], 
  {2}
 ]; 
 data
]

d = {{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
f[d, 1, 3]
```

> {{1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
>     1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
>
> {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
>     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}